# Algorithm to Rate limit remote requests

Tags: algorithm, distributed

Assume I have a very large pool of requests that I want to send to a remote host. Like any server, the remote host has limited capacity. All the messages must eventually be delivered, and timeliness is preferable but not important. I have no way to know this capacity of the remote host other than by monitoring the  response times and/or failure rates of the requests I send.

I need to develop an algorithm to send requests at a rate that maximizes throughput without making the remote host fall over.

The best output variable seems to be the period between requests, such that request N is dispatched M nanoseconds after request N-1.

How should I approach the problem of determining the optimal rate? Are there any papers I can build off of? Or can anyone come up with some wonder-algorithm? Anyone done this before?

NOTE: Token bucket is not the answer I'm looking for either. I'm already using something very much like a token bucket, but I'm looking for a way to determine the rate at which tokens should be added to the bucket.

Comment: It's going to depend on what the server does if you overload it. Will it fall over and die, or just fail to respond and then recover after some (unknown) time? Will the server cut you off if you exceed the limit too frequently?

Comment: In this case, it depends. I'm actually managing different pools for about 9000 separate remote hosts, none of which I have control over.

EDIT: Hit enter too early -- some will time out, some will refuse connections, some will return HTTP 50x. I don't really foresee many other outcomes than that.

Comment: Also, I should mention that delivering the same request multiple times isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't come up with a magic algorithm when I wrote my web crawler. We used some heuristics that seemed to do a reasonably good job, although certainly not perfect.

First, we looked at the site's robots.txt file. If it had a crawl-delay entry, we honored that by never exceeding it.

For other servers, we would keep a running average of the time required for the last n requests (I think we settled on a value of 5), and we'd make sure that we never sent requests more frequently than that average. We measured time from when we made the request until we'd finished processing the response.

If a server timed out, the time for that request would go into the running average.

If we got a 50x from the server, we'd delay a fairly long time (five minutes or more) before making another request to that server. Repeated 50x responses would cause us to just stop making requests until somebody could go see what the problem was.

We also kept track of the 40x responses. Lots of not found or access denied would cause the crawler to stop processing a domain and raise a flag so somebody could look at it.

We had a distributed crawler. No individual crawler would make concurrent requests to the same domain, and we had some cross-server communication that made it unusual for multiple servers to make concurrent requests to the same domain.

I'm sure that this didn't *maximize* throughput on any particular server, but it did keep the larger sites very busy. More importantly for us, it prevented us (mostly, anyway) from being blocked by many sites.

We also had special-case handling for many sites with APIs. Some would say what their request limits were, and we'd adjust our settings for those sites so we rode right at the line. But we only had a few dozen of those. Manually configuring request frequency for 9,000 servers (and then keeping up with changes) would not be realistic. However, you might be able to manually configure the dozen or two.